# Microphone on iPod Touch 7G with Safari not working

Tags: ios, safari, microphone, ipod

I have a problem using the microphone on Safari. The device is an iPod Touch 7G with iOS 14.4. I tried several websites (like translate.google.com, de.mictests.com, ...) that are using an microphone but the websites all didn't find the microphone. We tried the option to enable mikrophone for all websites but they didn't find it, too.

When using an app like the deault recorder app on iOS 14.4 the microphone works. When using an iPhone or iPad the mircophone on safari works, too.

It seams that Apple cuts off using the microphone on Safari for iPod Touch?

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try settings > safari > microphone > always allow